# calling sensor api from java script

Tags: javascript, html, sensors

I would like to write a java script which will return sensor data of a platform. this java script will run on both android and windows in HTML5.

For the code which will run on windows I want to call Win7 API of sensors (not the Win8 one).
I want this code to run on win7 and win8 - desktop and metro mode.

what is the best way to call sensors API from the java script?

I want it to run on IE10  and more and also on chrome.

this is win7 api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318964(v=vs.85).aspx

NOTE: I don't want to use the support of HTML5 for some sensors, since I want the low level of data.

thanks.

Comment: I am not sure javascript is the best technology to do that, especially if you don't want to use the HTML5 APIs. Javascript runs in a security sandbox preventing, among other things, the use of native apis.
If you, however, for some strange reason need to access native windows api from javascript the only way I can think of is via a signed Java applet and a JNI binding, though I am not sure that would work.